# Why can I make a vector of abstract objects?

Tags: c++, vector, abstract-class

Why does this code compile at all?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
        virtual void a() = 0;
};

int main()
{
        vector<A> a;    //won't fail
        //A b;            //that will
}
```

Comment: Tested under g++ version: Debian 4.7.1-7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because templates. You don't instanciate anything. Try using `resize()`, or some other method. That should fail.

Comment: All methods of a template class are not infatuated until called in some context.  This let's you do things like have an operator< on vectors that relies on an operator< on elements.  Now SFINAE does this cleaner, but is harder to do right.